# Message is not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html

My problem is that the message is not displayed  when the password and the username are correct. Then my page go on foredeck.php . This part is good but  why my message is not displayed before it change web page ? In the case of the password or the unsername is not correct the second message appear. I have a problem just with the first :
echo "alert('Connexion Réussite')";

```
 <?php
    $msg = '';

    if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
       && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

       if ($_POST['username'] == 'foredeck' && 
          $_POST['password'] == 'foredeck1') {
          $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
          $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
          $_SESSION['username'] = 'tutorialspoint';
               $msg ='Connexion Réussite';
          echo $msg= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($msg)</script>";

         header("location: foredeck.php");

       }else {
          $msg='Identifiant ou Mot de Passe incorrecte';
          $msg =  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg')</script>";
       }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Where did you output `$msg`? I don't see anything like `echo $msg`. And also the first echo will be skipped because you've set a header redirect, use javascript with a timer and then redirect the user.

Comment: i will edit my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `Javascript` runs on the browser and `PHP` runs on the server, so the code work step by step as you are expecting here. Here the PHP code runs before the javascript code which is the reason that you would get redirected before JS code runs.

You can solve this by:

- Removing the header(`location: foredeck.php`).
- and putting `window.location = 'foredeck.php';` in the javascript.

This will make your alert work first and then redirect it to the foredeck.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP `header(location)` is executed before `alert()` which is JS,so the alert is not being displayed and the page gets redirected. So use `window.location` in `<script>`(redirect code in JS)  instead of `header(location)`

```
  <?php
      $msg = '';

      if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
         && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

         if ($_POST['username'] == 'foredeck' && 
            $_POST['password'] == 'foredeck1') {
            $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
         $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
         $_SESSION['username'] = 'tutorialspoint';
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Connexion Réussite');
window.location.href='foredeck.php';
</script>";



      }else {
         $msg =  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Identifiant ou Mot de Passe incorrecte')</script>";
      }
   }
   ?>
```

The alert will be shown first and redirected when pressed ok..

Comment: @A.V Welcome..Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `header()` will execute the redirection immediately. Use the header refresh with a timer like this:

```
 header("refresh:5; url=wherever.php");
```

I hope this will help you!